# Class of function satisfying an inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I want to find out what class of real-valued $C^2$-functions $f$, defined on an interval $I$ containing a point  $x^*$,satisfies this $$ f'(x^*)f'(\xi)\ge \frac{-1}{|x^*-\xi|^\alpha} \quad\forall \xi\in I$$ where $\alpha >0$ is fixed. I tried some ideas and made some computations, but without success. Any idea is welcome.
Note that obviously, every monotone function satisfies the condition.